Can I use 'Actor A' and 'Actor B' as placeholders if I don't know the actor/actress's name while posting a question?
I'm watching a foreign movie (e.g., French) and want to ask a question, but I don't know the actor/actress's name,
and I couldn't find it on IMDB's cast list.

As long as the question is clear, I don't see why not. Do you need to use the Actor's name? Unless the question is about an actor, its often best to refer to the character.

If you're not sure who the actors/characters are in a scene that you're trying to describe, the best thing to do is to identify them by a physical description, quote their dialogue and offer a timestamp so that other people can work out what scene you're referring to.
What will typically happen then is that some helpful soul will, even if they can't answer your question, edit the names of the various characters into the question for you.
Don't let perfect be the enemy of good. If you think it's a decent question, then ask it and we'll bash it into shape together.
